# Issues with retrieving 2D arrays from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a 2D array representing a maze, and within a loop, I am updating the state of this array.  After each update, I add the 2D array into the ArrayList.  My issue is when I try to access any of the states within the ArrayList, it always gives me the final state of the 2D array.  When I am making a change to the 2D array, am I also making changes to all of the previous states stored within the ArrayList?

Comment: _"When I am making a change to the 2D array, am I also making changes to all of the previous states stored within the ArrayList?"_ - Yes

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Adding an answer for a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found, editing the 2D array will modify those you put in the ArrayList

To stop this, try adding temporary 2D arrays with a copy of the data

```
List<int[][]> list;
int[][] maze;
int[][] temp = new int[maze.length][];
for(int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++)
{
    temp[i] = new int[maze[i].length];
    System.arraycopy(maze[i], 0, temp[i], 0, maze[i].length);
}
list.add(temp);
```

This would be good to add as a method, taking in the 2D array to append, and the List to be appended to

```
private void append(int[][] maze, List<int[][]> list)
{
    //the above code
}
```

Note that if maze is a 2D array of Objects, you may need to clone them as well (primitives/immutables like int/double/boolean/String are fine)

Comment: Much appreciated, I will attempt to implement something along these lines!